# updating textbox value based on change in drop down menu in php

Tags: javascript, php

I have the function below that populates a drop down list. There is the textbox that I need to update with value when the user changes the dropdown value. Some guidance regarding this issue would be very much appreciated. Thanks!!

```
function populateEnrollment($value){
    foreach($value as $productid => $prod) if ($productid ==101){ 
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td width=350 class="tah11">'. $prod["name"] .'</td>' ;
    echo '<td width=80 class="tah11"><div align="center"> <select name="enrollName"id="enrollNameId" >';
    foreach ($prod["membershipType"] as $type){
           echo '<option value="' .$type["price"] .'">'.$type["name"] . ' at $' . $type["price"] . '</option>';                                                
    } // end of foreach membershipTypen                            
            echo '</select>';
            echo '</td>';               

    } // end of products foreach
echo '<td width=80 class="tah11"><div align="center"><input name="enrollCost" readonly type="text" id="enrollCostId" value="'.$type["price"].'"></td>';
echo '</tr>';
} // end of function populateEnrollment
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some Javascript that will achieve what I think you're looking for:

```
document.getElementById('enrollNameId').addEventListener('change', function(){
   document.getElementById('enrollCostId').value = this.value;
});
```

[<kbd>JSFiddle</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/HDm7z/)

Comment: I am assuming I need to put this between <script type="text/javascript"> </script> tags.

This page is a php file that is getting included another page two level deep and I just added <script></script> tags to it. I am assuming that should be okay ...

But inserting this code did not work? Am I doing sth wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
$( "option" ).change(function() {
  $("#enrollCostId").html() = $(this).val();
});
```

Insert this jQuery in your page between the `<script>` tags.

Comment: I am assuming I need to put this between <script type="text/javascript"> </script> tags.

This page is a php file that is getting included another page two level deep and I just added <script></script> tags to it. I am assuming that should be okay ...

But inserting this code did not work? Am I doing sth wrong?